# Is there any possible to access variables which is inside the kubernetes container

Tags: kubernetes

I need to access the variable which is inside the kubernetes pod without login to the pod container

Comment: I don't think you can. I would recommend to set this variables via Deployment spec or in ConfigMap.

Comment: ok thanks....will try

Answer (score 1):

If the variables are exposed via Environment you can try using

````sh
kubectl describe po env_pod | grep -A 10 Environment                                                        
    Environment:
      DB_URL:                       x.x.x.x
      LC_TIMEOUT:                   10
      SNS_QUEUE_REGION:             us-west-2
    Mounts:
      /var/log from shared-log-storage (rw)
      ```
````

Comment: can we read extra variables that was set by app other than the variables we are passing from kubernetes?

Comment: Typically, the Variables set by the app will only be available to the session. Do you mind sharing how the app sets the variables?

Comment: ..sorry I'm not getting you .i have a container in which microservice app is running sometimes the container runs fine but inside the microservice app due to getting lots of logs sometimes it stops so i have to take any metrics of microservice app with that i will increase or decrease the pod count

Comment: In short can anyone tell how to fetch the application metrics from the container

Comment: In that case, the best bet is to instrument your application with an APM(AppDynamics, New relic,etc...). If you are looking for opensource metric collection, you may be interested in instrumenting your application with Prometheus. Otherwise, you can fetch metrics from logs using ELK or splunk.